# Get generated CheckBox ID onLoad

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How can I get the generated CheckBox ID when it load using javascript?

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_select" type="checkbox" runat="server" onclick="javascript:CheckCheckBox(this);" OnLoad="javascript:onLoad(this)"  />

function onLoad(elem) {
                        alert(elem.getElementById());
                    }
```

Comment: on page load or on any event?

Comment: is this code dynamic and you want checkbox id or you need checkbox id in the onLoad method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below snippet will give you array of all matched id's,

```js
//on page load event
var matches = [].concat(document.querySelectorAll('[id*=CheckBox_select]')["0"]);
console.log(matches[0].id)

//or

var checboxId = document.querySelectorAll('[id*=CheckBox_select]')[0];
console.log(checboxId.id)
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="AutoGeneratedID_CheckBox_select" />
```

Comment: It only gives me the first value id and not the rest. It keep repeat

Comment: basically it return array of all matched elements, if you need all elements then you need to make loop through it